Question on quadrilaterals

The distance between two parallel sides $AB$ and $CD$ of a trapezoid is $12$ units.
$AB = 24$ units; $CD = 15$ units. $E$ is the mid-point of $AB$ . $O$ is the point of intersection
of $DE$ with $AC$ . Prove that the area of this quadrilateral $EBCO$ is
$112$ sq. units.

I tried this with finding $area(ABCD)=234$ then I calculated $area(EBC)=72=area(EAD)$. For finding area of $EOBC$ I need to get area of $EOC$ , then I got that $area(EDC)=234-2(72)=90$.
I don't know how to approach this now, please help if you can.

Hi. You can put numbers, and in general mathematical things, between two dollar signs ($). In this way, your question will look better. Good luck!

You've made a good start using several area sums & differences, but here's a somewhat alternate approach using just a single difference of triangle areas. The figure below represents the described quadrilateral, but with the line $FOG$ (perpendicular to $AB$ and $DC$) added so $F$ is on $AB$ and $G$ is on $CD$.

Since $AE \parallel CD$, then $\measuredangle EAO = \measuredangle DCO$ and $\measuredangle AEO = \measuredangle CDO$, with $\measuredangle AOE = \measuredangle COD$ as they are vertically opposite angles, so $\triangle AEO \sim \triangle CDO$. Thus, with $\lvert AE\rvert = \frac{\lvert AB\rvert}{2} = 12$, then
$$\frac{\lvert OG\rvert}{\lvert FO\rvert} = \frac{\lvert DC\rvert}{\lvert AE\rvert} = \frac{15}{12} = \frac{5}{4} \;\;\to\;\; \lvert OG\rvert = \frac{5}{4}\lvert FO\rvert$$
We also have
$$\lvert FO\rvert + \lvert OG\rvert = 12 \;\;\to\;\; \frac{9}{4}\lvert FO\rvert = 12 \;\;\to\;\; \lvert FO\rvert = \frac{16}{3}$$
With $A()$ being the area function, then using the one-half base times altitude triangle area formula, we get
$$A(\triangle AEO) = \frac{\lvert AE\rvert \times \lvert FO \rvert}{2} = \frac{12\times \frac{16}{3}}{2} = 32$$
We also have
$$A(\triangle ABC) = \frac{\lvert AB\rvert \times \lvert FG \rvert}{2} = \frac{24\times 12}{2} = 144$$
Finally, there's
$$A(EBCO) = A(\triangle ABC) - A(\triangle AEO) = 144 - 32 = 112$$
